# Does sheafifying with respect to a new site destroy the already existent descent properties?

Tags: category-theory, schemes, grothendieck-topologies

This is probably a rather obvious question (either obviously true or wrong). Given a presheaf on the category of schemes that satisfies descent with respect to some site. If we sheafify the presheaf with respect to another site, then does it preserve its sheaf property with respect to the first site?

Comment: Topologies used in algebraic geometry are usually related – one is finer than the other or the other way around. (There are exceptions.) A sheaf for one topology is automatically a sheaf for any coarser topology, so, for example, if you take a Zariski sheaf and do étale sheafification you end up with an étale sheaf, but every étale sheaf is already a Zariski sheaf.

Comment: What I had in my mind was cdh-site and etale site. Homotopy $K$-theory satisfies cdh-descent, especially this implies algebraic $K$-theory satisfies descent with respect to abstract blow-ups of smooth schemes. Does this imply that etale $K$-theory also satisfy the abstract blow-up descent?